# react-pdf cors to gcp storage

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, storage

I want to get `pdf` file from my `GCP` , but I get `CORS` error. Ok , np . I've tried to find how to solve this issue in `GCP` . Found this example :

https://bitmovin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000059353-How-do-I-set-up-CORS-for-my-Google-Cloud-Storage-Bucket-

I've following all of this instructions :

```
echo '[{"origin": ["*"],"responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],"method": ["GET", "HEAD"],"maxAgeSeconds": 3600}]' > cors-config.json

gsutil cors set cors-config.json gs://booknote-pdf-files-store
```

[image]

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress'

import styles from './styles'



const Application = ({ classes }) => {
  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null)
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1)

  const onDocumentLoadSuccess = ({ numPages }) => {
    setNumPages(numPages)
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <Document
        file="https://storage.cloud.google.com/booknote-pdf-files-store/living_in_the_light.pdf"
        onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
        renderMode="svg"
        loading={<CircularProgress />}>
        <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
      </Document>
    </div>
  )
}

Application.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.instanceOf(Object).isRequired,
}
```

But i still get CORS error. What am I doing wrong ? If you need additional info , pls let me know

Also you can check npm package which I use for this purpose :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `gsutil` command for setting up cors actually worked ( I'd double-check just to be sure, run: `gsutil cors get gs://booknote-pdf-files-store` and see if the changes have been reflected ). Simply put, [`react-pdf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf) relies a lot on [`PDF.js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs-dist) and so it is possible that this is caused by how PDF.js gets the file from the server.

Taken straight from PDF.js FAQ, "PDF.js runs with the same permissions as any other JavaScript code, which means it cannot do cross origin requests".

There are a few workarounds available at your disposal though, one of them is using a proxy that return the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header if it's not at the Same Origin. Thus, your request for the file will not be sent to GCS but will be made to your proxy which will forward them to GCS. I highly giving [PDF.js' FAQ](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-xhr) a read, surely it will point you in the right direction.